# It's possible re-read .env file on Laravel 5.X

Tags: laravel-5, environment-variables

I needs to work with .env file on laravel.

But on some circumstances I need put a new file (.env) with new values, and I need update all environment vars and best way it's read .env file.

I don't see how to re-read .env file on Laravel (read for re-assign values to all env vars)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do? When are you trying to update the .env file and when do you need to read it? Laravel reads the .env file on every request made.

Comment: Sorry for my english. On new installation, of my app, i copy default .env and after copy modify values for APP_ENV to producction, and others such, APP_KEY, MAIL_*, DB_*. After write on disk new .env i dont' see changes on *_ENV variables. Actually I use `\Dotenv::load(base_path());`for re-read .env file and update this vars.